# Power BI fact and dim tables not associated in a matrix

Tags: matrix, powerbi

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoqWX.png)I have two simple tables, one is a fact table and one is a dimension table. I've linked the dimension table to the fact table with a (*-to-1) relationship. However, when I create a matrix and try to display the values from the dimension table associated with the columns of the fact table, I get the same value, as shown in the screenshots. How can I display the value of the token from the dimension table for each column of the fact table?

I tried to delete and install again from a different exe. I tried to switch off/on the computer, I tried with related and calculate DAX functions. I spend a lot of time exchanging with chat GPT and could not figure out what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the dimension table column to the Matrix rows, and add fact columns to the Matrix values.

The relationship you have is `One` directional, meaning the fact table will not filter the dimension (and this is okay). This is why it is returning the first value of the dimension table effectively without any relationship, hence why they are all the same.

**You also need to ensure your strings are trimmed that are used in the relationship.**
In PowerQuery you can trim columns easily, right-click on the column header, `Transform` > `Trim`.

Comment: Than you for support on this question. I tried to add the dim table column to the matrix row and the fact table column to the matrix value before posting the question. However, I still have the same problem : the matrix shows only one value. If you have any other solution to test I would be very pleased to try it. Have a good day.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding "I still have the same problem : the matrix shows only one value". What are you expecting to see? This? https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnq5f.png

Comment: [link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuogRpfc4rRVgZ8nJ4IuMvXiYMCKmg?e=pVfs3y) Yes, the result in your picture would response to my problem, however when I do the same setup as you (tocken in rows and first crypto in value) I have only one value [link](https://1drv.ms/i/s!AuogRpfc4rRVgZ8t-wN8jd6pW6nQpw?e=oFwm9U)

Comment: Updated answer above - you need to trim your columns in PowerQuery as there were some hidden spaces/characters that meant the relationship didn't work. Seems this question/project is also related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77868334/related-with-2-differents-tables

Comment: Indeed, I had a space before the token value because of the transform column operation I realized previously. After deleting this space, I was able to get all the information I wanted. Thanks a lot for your help and resolving the issue.