# Related() with 2 differents Tables

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop, data-cleaning

_Hi, I have two simple separate tables connected with a one-to-many relation. When I try to add a calculated column to the fact table with a related DAX formula, the result is all blank. However, when I create a reference table from the Facts one, an do the same, then it works. I can't understand why the first one does not work : it is as if there were no relation between the 2 tables ?

Thanks in advance for your help.
[Here is the link to my PBIX file.](https://1drv.ms/u/s!An2aQoxg76Kv8kAODfNHwhoZ_ald?e=2oHEhV)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have different values in the columns. Observe:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I suggest you properly clean your data in PQ.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer Davide ! Indeed... I keep in mind the len stuff !